# Key hash not getting verified to login with facebook sdk

Tags: java, android, facebook, key

I want to use facebook sdk. I have created an app in fb developers console, also created a hash key using

```
 C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_131\bin>keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore C:\Users\siddhi jambhale\.android\debug.keystore | "C:\Program Files (x86)\openssl-0.9.8k_X64\bin\openssl.exe" sha1 -binary | "C:\Program Files (x86)\openssl-0.9.8k_X64\bin\openssl.exe" base64



Illegal option:  jambhale\.android\debug.keystore

keytool -exportcert [OPTION]...

Exports certificate

Options:

 -rfc                            output in RFC style
 -alias <alias>                  alias name of the entry to process
 -file <filename>                output file name
 -keystore <keystore>            keystore name
 -storepass <arg>                keystore password
 -storetype <storetype>          keystore type
 -providername <providername>    provider name
 -providerclass <providerclass>  provider class name
 -providerarg <arg>              provider argument
 -providerpath <pathlist>        provider classpath
 -v                              verbose output
 -protected                      password through protected mechanism

Use "keytool -help" for all available commands
2jmj7l5rSw0yVb/hgfgfr/YBwk=
```

Above its showing illegal option but got the key, tried to use this key but not working.

As showing illegal option I tried to cut down space between username i.e siddhijambhale. And tried the key I got. But this is also not working.

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_131\bin>keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore C:\Users\siddhijambhale\.android\debug.keystore | "C:\Program Files (x86)\openssl-0.9.8k_X64\bin\openssl.exe" sha1 -binary | "C:\Program Files (x86)\openssl-0.9.8k_X64\bin\openssl.exe" base64
```

X4RAFa1I3Ucy/kBvdofrerffwS0=
[image]

I get this error, and the key shown in the error is different than the key I have got from cmd and which is stored in the fb developers console.

What to do for this?

Please help. Thank you..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

run this code in your one of activity...

```
try {
            PackageInfo info = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(
                    "YOUR_PACAKGE_NAME", 
                    PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
            for (Signature signature : info.signatures) {
                MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
                md.update(signature.toByteArray());
                Log.d("KeyHash:", Base64.encodeToString(md.digest(), Base64.DEFAULT));
                }
        } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {

        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {

        }
```

it will give you keyHash and Add that keyhash in your Facebook A/C.

Comment: try to print e.printStackTrace() in both catch block..There is some error.plz check..

Comment: ok this worked, but can you please explain how this hash key works for facebook? why hash key from cmd does not work?